# How to update Sheets by importing Gdrive folder list changes by inserting rows not appending?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that runs a script pulling in a Google Drive folder list. In the same sheet but into separate columns I'm manually adding relevant information for various rows which gets me to my questions:

(1) Can I get my Google Drive folder list script to pull in the folders in alphabetical order? 
(I'm right now sorting it via another script)

Script that pulls in my folder structure:

```
 // Get Folder Tree
 function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
   try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('raw-data');
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name", "Date", "URL", "Last Updated", "Description", "Size"]);

    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
 };
```

(2) How can the script that pulls in a Google drive folder list add new folders by inserting them between rows instead of appending them at the end?
I want to make sure that my notes from the additional columns doesn't get mixed up with wrong rows once the folder structure is updated.

Any & all help is much appreciated!

Comment: sheet.clear() deletes everything on the sheet each run, so does your script save your comment/notes?

Comment: @JagannathanAlagurajan right! I had changed that already in the script earlier. My comments didn't get erased because I'm writing my comments/notes on a separate sheet that also displays the pulled in the Google Drive Folder list. The problem is that if I have a folder that gets a new subfolder and I sort it alphabetically then my comments will be one row off starting from that folder change. This is my big problem.

Comment: How do you prevent duplicate entries of folder in your sheet which has your comments? I ask this because you can modify that code easily to prevent erasing you comments. Also the code above is incomplete, it doesn't actually show how you handle the addition of a new subfolder. Or how you prevent addition of duplicates in you sheet

Comment: I am very new to Google Script and I haven't figured out: (1) how new subfolders are added, (2) how to pull them in alphabetically, (3) or how to keep my comments in the same sheet. Any chance @JagannathanAlagurajan you could give me some pointers?

Comment: Ok, each one of those can be done in-app scripts. However, this forum might not be a right place for broad questions like that. This forum is for a more focused problem and questions should include your code. My suggestion is to split this question into three new questions, show the work you put into coding for each question. Ask advice on a specific thing you are stuck on. Broad questions like this will mostly go un answered. This link is a good place to get started. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app